# Managing a Python Monorepo in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, monorepo

I'm experimenting with monorepos & python. The idea is having multiple projects in the same repo, each project should have its own virtualenv.

I find it kinda cumbersome managing all of that in PyCharm.

PyCharm supports managing multiple projects in with different venvs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-multiple-projects.html?_ga=2.5681206.409054178.1602169802-543218074.1500382704

But it's not very friendly if you have many projects, I will have to "open" and "attach" each and every one of them.

Let's see an example in this repo:

Under the `project` directory I have 2 projects:

[image: Project Layout Example]

The 2 projects directories are marked in **bold** (just like the root one), basically meaning they are "PyCharm projects".

Under the preferences window, you can see all the projects:

[image]

But there's no option of adding new projects there.
If I had a 3rd project, I would have to open it and attach it to the current window.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way of marking a sub-directory as a project?
Imagine cloning a repository with 10 projects or more, configuring all the settings on PyCharm is going to be very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can [share some of the files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems) into the `.idea` folder via your repository. This folder and particularly the `.idea/modules.xml` file contains all the configuration details for your project(s).

Therefore, you only have to do the setup once (or as projects are added) then the configuration will be replicated.